# Ruby: tap not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, tap

Writing code for my application_controller to translate user input into query, this works:

```
result_set =  model  # some implementation of ActiveRecord::Base as a Class
.includes(:metric_template => [:group]) #still need to abstract this
.where(f)  
.order(sort_string)
.limit(rows)
.offset((page-1)*rows)
```

this does not work because the where method seems not to be called:

```
result_set =  model
.includes(:metric_template => [:group])  #still need to abstact this
.tap{|o| o.where(f) if f}
.order(sort_string)
.limit(rows)
.offset((page-1)*rows)
```

I'd really like .tap() to work here.  Why doesn't it?  Is it not available as a class method?  Can it be convinced?

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the fact that this is not really a method chain, it's the Arel DSL. In any case, I'm sure there's an Arel construct you can use in place of the tap. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What are you trying to get tap to do here?

Comment: The objective is to conditionally call model.where() in the method chain.  I am prepared to always call where, and conditionally override a filter like '1=1', but that has a bit of a.... well, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you (effectively) want:

```
result_set = model.
  includes(:metric_template => [:group]).  #still need to abstact this
  order(sort_string).
  limit(rows).
  offset((page-1)*rows)
result_set = result_set.where(f) if f
```

This isn't really a situation that calls for `tap`, which is most useful for operating on an item within a method without changing the method's return value (for reasons that sepp2k has explained).

Also, it would probably be best to move this query into a method inside the model.

Comment: Success!! Thank you.  Interesting suggestion about moving this into a model, possibly a mixin, because what I'm doing is receiving request parameters from jqGrid and dynamically returning the correct results (filtered/ordered/paged).  I am doing this for several models.

Answer (score 2):

`where` gets called just fine. The problem is that `where` doesn't have any visible side-effects - it's used only for its return value.

Since `tap` doesn't do anything with the block's return value, there's no point in using `tap` with a block that doesn't have visible side-effects.

Comment: Yes, I see that I was expecting something unreasonable from tap. Thanks.